# CSS: Styling a link based on its href

Tags: jquery, css, anchor

I have a 3rd party link on my website which I want to style. but it don't have any class or id which I can target. Only thing it have is its unique href value. 
Is it possible to style a anchor tag based on its href value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use href css selector to style `a` tag based on link:

```
a[href="your url here"]{
    background:red;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/pnc5fk68/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use css `attribute` selector like:

```
a[href="http://google.com"]{
   your css code here ...
}
```

More information **[here](https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/)**.

Thanks.